# WebClient with Mono for android to create file on server

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, webclient

I would like to write data to a file on a server. Therefore, I use the following code:

```
            System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            string webAddress = "https://sd2dav.1und1.de/"; //1&1 Webdav
            string destinationFilePath = webAddress + "testfile.txt";
            webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword");
            Stream stream = webClient.OpenWrite(destinationFilePath,"PUT");

            UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, uniEncoding))
            {
                sw.Write("text");
                sw.Flush();
            }

            webClient.Dispose();
```

This works fine when compiled with Visual Studio 2008, .net 3.5 and executed on Windows 7. However, I would like to do this with Mono for Android (4.4.54). Here, the code executes, but nothing happens: The file is not created on the server.

Is this a bug in Mono for Android or is anything wrong with the code above? Do you know a way to get this working?

**Update:** I filed a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10163 regarding this issue. Hopefully, the guys from Xamarin will take care of this. Furthermore, I presented an alternative way of sending the data to the server at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786214/alternative-to-webclient-openwrite.